# How to fill dropdown list options with values from database in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a little bit of a newbie question.

I have a basic form with a dropdown list that looks like the following :

```
## apply.html.erb

<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
 <%= f.label 'parent' , 'Category' %>
 <%= f.select :category, [["foo", 0 ], ["bar", 1 ]] %>
<% end %>
```

The dropdown list values are `"foo"` and `"bar"`.

I am trying to pull values directly from a database. The problem is that I have no idea how to organize the `controller` and the `model`.

Here is the controller :

```
## Welcome_controller.rb
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def apply
    @category = 'foobar'
  end
end
```

I have not generated the controller yet. I can not find any convincing answers to my question or tutorial on the internet.

Any idea how I can make it happen?

** EDIT **

So I have been doing some edits.Here is what I have:

The view

```
## apply.html.erb    
<%= form_for @category, as: :category do |f| %>
 <%= f.label 'Categories' %>
 <%= f.select :category, @category %>
<% end %>
```

The controller :

```
## welcome_controller.rb
def apply
    @category = Category.new
    @categories = Category.pluck(:id, :name)
  end
```

The model :

```
## Category.rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I get the following in the terminal :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `categories_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ffb7c5a2808>:0x007ffb7c2814f8>):
    3: <div id="category_block">
    4:   <span>What would you like to get financed ?</span>
    5: 
    6:   <%= form_for @category, as: :category do |f| %>
    7:     <%= f.label 'Categories' %>
    8:     <%= f.select :category, @category %>
    9:   <% end %>

app/views/welcome/apply.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_welcome_apply_html_erb___747255529581383389_70359048261520'
```

It looks like the problem comes from `@category = Category.new` because when I replace `Category.new` with a string like `' foobar'`, the error disappears.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read more about the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/). This is a pretty basic question, and you'll probably have the answer if you actually take the time to read and learn.

That said, the info you provided is lacking so I'll just assume.

First, I assume you have a `Category` model. It should be placed in `app/models/category.rb`:

```
def Category
  ...
end
```

Next, you're not actually querying anything from the database. You can do it this way:

```
## app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def apply
    @category = Category.new
    @categories = Category.pluck(:name, :id)
  end
end
```

`Category.new` generates a new instance of the `Category` (`category.rb`) object.
`Category.pluck(:name, :id)` generates this array: `[['foo', 1], ['bar', 2]]`, where `name` and `id` are attributes of the `Category` model (just change it to your liking).

Once you have your array stored in `@categories`, you can use it in your form like this:

```
## app/views/welcome/apply.html.erb

<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
 <%= f.label 'parent' %>
 <%= f.select :category, @categories %>
<% end %>
```

You're probably not planning to actually create a form for a `Category` considering that you have a dropdown for categories so you should just change it to something else. Also, take note of the file names. They're all lowercase and separated by underscores. (`Welcome_controller.rb` should be `welcome_controller.rb`)

** EDIT **

Now that you've added an object to the `form_for`, rails will automatically assign a path for your form unless you change it. For this case, the path is `categories_path`. Read more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

What you need to do is modify your `routes.rb` and add the following line:

```
resources :categories
```

That line will automatically generate routes that provide a mapping between HTTP verbs and URLs to controller actions.

Next you need to create a `CategoriesController`:

```
## app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    if @account_user.save
      redirect_to apply_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit! # MODIFY THIS
  end
end
```

Anyway, this is basically a walkthrough and you should be figuring this out yourself. There are a lot of resources out there -- it's not hard to find one. You can also check this out: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPy0GQJLZUM).

Comment: What should I put in the model method to pull the data from the database? Sorry , I'm pretty new in rails development

Comment: If you don't have any validations, associations, nor instance methods to put, you can leave it blank. Just make sure you ran the migration.

Comment: What's the stack trace? It may be because you didn't run your migration. There are a number ways to get that error. Make sure you read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) before anything else.

Comment: The error comes from `@category = Category.new`. When I replace `Category.new` by a string , I do not get the error method anymore

Comment: It should be like this: `<%= form_for @category, as: :category, url: [post_form_route_url] do |f| %>`. Ideally `@category` should be an object not a string, but do whatever fits your needs.

Comment: I can't get it to work. I am going to edit so you can take a look at it

Comment: I edited my post too. Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPy0GQJLZUM). You need to learn the fundamentals first.